Django HttpStreamingResponse Not Streaming
I have a very interesting issue with the Django HttpStreamingResponse. Our server calls OpenAI Text Completion API in streaming mode, upon receiving the chunks from OpenAI, we incrementally parse the chunks and stream complete JSON objects back to our clients. Below are some code snippets:
views.py
class StreamViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def stream(self, request):
       ...
       json_stream = agent.get_json_objects()
       return StreamingHttpResponse(json_stream, content_type="application/json")

agents.py
    def stream(self):
        yield from self.json_agent.get_json_stream()

json_agent.py
def get_data_stream(self):
    # This calls OpenAI text completion API with stream=True
    stream_response = self.get_text_completion(user_preference, stream=True)

    # Create an incremental json parser
    json_stream_parser = JsonStreamParser()

    for chunk in stream_response:
        if chunk.choices and chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None:
            json_stream_parser.feed(chunk.choices[0].delta.content)
            yield from json_stream_parser.parse()

json_parser.py
class JsonStreamParser:
    """A simple JSON stream parser that can parse a stream of JSON objects.
    Note it only works for an array of JSON objects, which means the input
    must contain a valid JSON array, at any point of the stream, that starts with '[' and ends with ']'.
    It will parse the JSON objects in the array and ignores anything outside of the array.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = ""
        self.index = 0
        self.open_braces = 0
        self.start_index = -1
        self.array_started = False

    def feed(self, data):
        self.buffer += data

    def parse(self):
        parsed = []
        while self.index < len(self.buffer):
            if self.buffer[self.index] == '[':
                self.array_started = True

            if self.buffer[self.index] == '{' and self.array_started:
                # If the start_index is -1, then we have found the start of a json object
                if self.start_index == -1:
                    self.start_index = self.index
                self.open_braces += 1

            elif self.buffer[self.index] == '}':
                self.open_braces -= 1
                # If the open_braces is 0, then we have found a complete json object
                if self.open_braces == 0 and self.start_index != -1:
                    j_obj = self.buffer[self.start_index:self.index+1]
                    parsed.append(j_obj)
                    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    # However, it will not work with
                    # parsed.append(json.loads(j_obj))
                    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                    # Reset the start_index and the buffer
                    self.start_index = -1
                    self.buffer = self.buffer[self.index:]
                    self.index = 0
            self.index += 1

        return parsed

    def flush(self):
        self.buffer = ""
        self.index = 0

The middleware and apps I have installed to the django server are:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


This code works fine by streaming text back to our clients until I add json.loads() to the json_parser.py where I want it to return json object instead of texts.  What could be the issue that blocking the streaming and buffers all the data before flushing to the response?
I tried to remove some of the middleware but they seems not related.
I tried to write the generator code in different ways but didn't help.

Please provide a [mre] including the sample data that is provided to your class. Also what actually happens when you add the json.loads() to the program? Does it error out? All I can guess is that your program errored out since your parser is actually flawed. For example your parser will not work properly for inputs like {"a": "b}"}, etc.

JsonStreamParser.parse ought to yield and not return.
